# Community vision for proposals in area51

Tags: feature-request, area-51

In area51, it would be nice to have a community vision in addition to name & who it's for. I find that a lot of question proposals are subjective or open-ended, and attracting votes because they seem like "good questions." Currently, the only way to express this is in comments, but it seems less than appropriate.

A community vision would help unify what kinds of questions (much like the faq, but put in terms that the community understands) are considered expert.

Answer (score 1):

I see your point, but I think the potential community is supposed to shape the vision by asking sample questions.

Comment: Yeah, and I think it does work in most cases.  I think it's primarily for getting people on the same page from the get go.  That is to say, if you don't have all the experts right off the bat, you can still steer the community in the right direction.